# JSF2 set a UISelectItem to not render. With a custom MenuRenderer

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a managed bean that contains a collection of UISelectItem instances.
How can i tell one instance to not render? Setting the `selectitem.setRendered(false)` still renderes that item... I'd like to manipulate the UiSelectItem instance.

So basicly i have a `h:selectOneMenu` that gets populated by this collection by `f:selectItems`. But some of these items i don't want to be displayed.

Thank you

**UPDATE:**
Looks like the rendered field is inherited by the UIComponentBase, but has no functionality.
Now I'm trying to make a custom MenuRenderer in combination with an extended UISelectitem that has a disabled field.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not a direct answer to your question, but maybe disabling the item would be enough for you? Looks like you could do (I haven't tried that):

```
<f:selectItem itemDisabled="true" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks, but i really don't want to disable it in the view. I'm now trying to extend UISelectItem and make a custom renderer, but it's not trivial.